# What is [linked]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I've just came across the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) tag. It has many questions tagged with it.

What surprised me was that the tag excerpt has

> [DO NOT USE] For linked list, use the tag [linked-list]

And most of the questions tagged with [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) tag are asking something about [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list).

- Shouldn't this tag be burninated?
- Shouldn't (almost) all the questions tagged with the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) tag be re-tagged with the [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) tag?
- Should this tag be made a synonym of [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list)?

Comment: Support for burnination. Againt synomize to [tag:linked-list] ("linked" is meaningless, and doesn't mean "linked-list" universally)

Comment: The tag excerpt was edited by me. I posted [Questions tagged with both “linked” and “list”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188949/questions-tagged-with-both-linked-and-list) nearly a year and a half  ago. However, people kept using this tag when they were supposed to use **linked-list**. Several months ago, I saw it having an excerpt, then I edited to what it is now, which didn't stop the tag being used, either.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Shouldn't this tag be burninated?

**Yes, let it burn.** This tag is...

- **Broad** - I see a mix of [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) and [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) questions on the first page alone
- **Ambiguous** - What does "linked" mean for the question? Clearly not a lot.
- **Not helpful** - What does "linked" contribute to the question? *Nothing.*
- **On the [list of tags which say "DO NOT USE"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266086/tags-which-should-not-be-used) in their excerpt** - It's a *really good indicator* of a tag which shouldn't exist.

> Shouldn't (almost) all the questions tagged with the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) tag be re-tagged with the [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) tag?

**Yes.** At least [509 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked+list) are tagged with both [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) and [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list). I think it's safe to say that most, if not all, of the questions should be re-tagged.

> Should this tag be made a synonym of [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list)?

**No.** [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) does not have the same meaning as [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list), which doesn't make it a great candidate for being a synonym. [From the FAQ on synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/159034)

> A tag synonym is usually a tag that has exactly the same meaning as some other tag.

I think we are safer just burning the tag and making sure that it doesn't resurface in the future.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this post?

Comment: @k_g On Meta, downvotes express disagreement.

Comment: @NobodyNada, no I understand that... My question is who would be against burinating a clearly broken tag.

Comment: @k_g, one challenge is that there are great gobs of worthless tags, and some people think it's not worth trying to fix. See, for example, [tag:internet] and [tag:delete] and . . . and . . . .

Comment: Oh, I see. I have noticed that a large proportion of meta (at least popular questions) is devoted to burination.

Answer (score 3):

[The deed is done.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked)

Approximately 72.4% of the questions tagged [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) were also tagged [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list), meaning that the majority of these questions were referring to [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list).

The rest were an amalgam of topics including (but not limited to):

1. Web links (`<a>` tag, etc.)
2. Links between various things (programming topics, languages, etc.)
3. Things not related to [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked) in any way

They have been cleaned up and retagged accordingly.

Comment: Now, I'm totally confused whether I have to accept your answer or Kevin's answer. What do you think I should do?

Comment: @CoolGuy That's totally up to you; it doesn't really matter, and I just posted here to let you know that the tag had been burninated.

Comment: I'd wait until the tag is officially removed to call it [meta-tag:status-completed]. It's a weekend, so there shouldn't be as many new questions, but there is a possibility someone will tag a question with it.

Comment: @KevinBrown That's true; one slipped in yesterday that I had to remove.